# Don't know how to build task 'environment' sitemap_generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using this [tutorial](http://cookieshq.co.uk/posts/creating-a-sitemap-with-ruby-on-rails-and-upload-it-to-amazon-s3/) for the gem [sitemap_generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator)

I was able to build the xml sitemap through the command rake sitemap:refresh but not anymore. It might be because I made an update of all my gems. Now I always get the error

```
Don't know how to build task 'environment'
```

rake sitemap:refresh --trace gives

```
** Invoke sitemap:refresh (first_time)
** Invoke sitemap:create (first_time)
** Invoke sitemap:require_environment (first_time)
** Execute sitemap:require_environment
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'environment'
/Users/Royal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
```

Rakefile is

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

#Rake tasks for sitemap
require 'sitemap_generator/tasks'
```

In lib/task/sitemap.rake I have

```
require 'aws'
require 'gems'

namespace :sitemap do
  desc 'Upload the sitemap files to S3'
  task upload_to_s3: :environment do
    puts 'Starting sitemap upload to S3...'
    s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
    bucket = s3.bucket(ENV['website'])
    Dir.entries(File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'sitemaps')).each do |file_name|
      next if %w(. .. .DS_Store).include? file_name
      path = "sitemaps/#{file_name}"
      file = File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'sitemaps', file_name)
      object = bucket.object(path)
      object.upload_file(file)
      puts "Saved #{file_name} to S3"
    end
  end


  desc 'Create the sitemap, then upload it to S3 and ping the search engines'
    task create_upload_and_ping: :environment do
      Rake::Task["sitemap:create"].invoke

      Rake::Task["sitemap:upload_to_s3"].invoke

      SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.ping_search_engines('http://website.co/sitemap.xml.gz')
    end
end
```

Thanks a lot for your help. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: You are invoking `Rake::Task["sitemap:create"].invoke` this is not shown on the snippet you paste, what does this look like?

Comment: Hi Chakaitos, 
Thanks for your help, sorry I am totally new to Rails. 
I rebuilt my project and I am going to update the post.

Comment: It looks like something wrong in your Rake::Task["sitemap:create"] task.  Can you post that code?

Answer (score -1):

I rebuilt the project and now it's working. Thanks for your help guys.